# Cannot access inner elements of array contained in JSON in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-16

I have the following code in which I am trying to extract JSON as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp2;

 CREATE TEMP  table tmp2 (
      c TEXT
    );

    insert into tmp2 values
    (' {"ChannelReadings": [
        { "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 47.67,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T12:57:43"
                },
                {
                    "Si": 47.22,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:02:43"
                },
                {
                    "Si": 47.6,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                },
                {
                    "Si": 47.5,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:12:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 14
        },
        {
            "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 2.893605,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 12
        },
        {
            "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 3.294233,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 13
        },
        {
            "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 3.294233,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 16
        }
    ],
    "DeviceSerialNumber": "894339",
    "RestartPointerNo": 5514732,
    "NewDownloadTable": false,
    "DataHashDto": "5Mckxoq42EeLHmLnimXv6A=="
}
     ');
```

I then tried to do the following code:

```
     select
            c::json ->> 'DeviceSerialNumber' as SerialNumber,
            c::json ->> 'ReadingsDto.ChannelID'::int as ChannelID,
            (c::json ->> 'RestartPointerNo')::int as RestartPointerNo,
            Readings.SI::Real,
            Readings.RAW::Real,
            Readings.Timestamp::timestamp as TimeStamp2

    from tmp2
    CROSS JOIN LATERAl    jsonb_array_elements(ChannelReadings ->'ReadingsDto') Readings;
```

and got the following error message:

[2023-11-17 00:09:25] [42703] ERROR: column "channelreadings" does not exist
[2023-11-17 00:09:25] Position: 398

I want to get the following results as follows:

```
DeviceSerialNumber channelID   Si                                      Raw         TimeStamp
------------------ ----------- --------------------------------------- ----------- -----------------------
894339             12          2.89                                    0           2023-01-24 13:07:43.000
894339             13          3.29                                    0           2023-01-24 13:07:43.000
894339             14          47.67                                   0           2023-01-24 12:57:43.000
894339             14          47.22                                   0           2023-01-24 13:02:43.000
894339             14          47.60                                   0           2023-01-24 13:07:43.000
894339             14          47.50                                   0           2023-01-24 13:12:43.000
894339             16          3.29                                    0           2023-01-24 13:07:43.000
'''
How do i get this desired results?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nested array, you have to use jsonb_array_elements() twice:

```
SELECT (c ->> 'DeviceSerialNumber')     AS serialnumber
     , (cr ->> 'ChannelId')::INT        AS channelid
     , (c ->> 'RestartPointerNo')::INT  AS restartpointerno
     , dto ->> 'Si'                     AS si
     , dto ->> 'Raw'                    AS raw
     , (dto ->> 'TimeStamp')::timestamp AS timestamp
FROM tmp2
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(c -> 'ChannelReadings') channelreadings(cr)
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(cr -> 'ReadingsDto')    readingsdto(dto);
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run that code:

[2023-11-17 00:59:02] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text -> unknown
[2023-11-17 00:59:02] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[2023-11-17 00:59:02] Position: 378

Comment: @ChrisAsi71 this code works fine if you change `c` to be `JSONB` instead of `TEXT` https://dbfiddle.uk/DMTBvSg8

Comment: @Nick 

That worked for me changing c to JSON B in my temp table

Thank you very much for your help on this.

Comment: @ChrisAsi71 no worries, glad you've got it working.